# numpy.genfromtxt skips/ignores last line in long tsv file

Tags: python, numpy, genfromtxt

I have a tsv-file from QuickDAQ with three columns of 200 000 values that I want to import into numpy. Problem is genfromtxt seems to miss the last line. The line is nothing out of the ordinary as far as I can see:

```
...
0,00232172012329102     0,0198968648910522      0,0049593448638916
0,00411009788513184     0,0142784118652344      0,00339150428771973
0,00499653816223145     0,00666630268096924     0,00308072566986084
```

Example of code that doesn't quite work:

```
In [245]: import numpy as np

In [246]: oompa = np.genfromtxt('C_20k_73_2.tsv',delimiter='\t',usecols=(0,1,2),unpack=True,skip_header=13,dtype=str)

In [248]: oompa[1]
Out[248]: 
array(['-0,00884926319122314', '-0,00379836559295654',
   '0,000106096267700195', ..., '0,0259654521942139',
   '0,0198968648910522', '0,0142784118652344'], 
  dtype='<U21')
```

The file had windows-style line breaks, I've tried removing these in vi but it doesn't make a difference. What could cause this kind of behaviour from genfromtxt and how could it be dealt with, preferably without manually editing the tsv file?

Comment: Print the `repr` of the last few lines of the file. That might give us a clue.

Comment: In [270]: repr(foo.readline())
Out[270]: "'0,00232172012329102\\t0,0198968648910522\\t0,0049593448638916\\n'"

In [271]: repr(foo.readline())
Out[271]: "'0,00411009788513184\\t0,0142784118652344\\t0,00339150428771973\\n'"

In [272]: repr(foo.readline())
Out[272]: "'0,00499653816223145\\t0,00666630268096924\\t0,00308072566986084\\n'"

In [273]: repr(foo.readline())
Out[273]: "'\\t\\n'"

In [274]: repr(foo.readline())
Out[274]: "'\\t\\n'"

Comment: Is this what you're after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the file seems to have some lines with just tabs. I'm surprised `np.genfromtxt` did not raise a `ValueError`. One way to prevent the problem would be to remove those empty tab lines. Another might be to use the `invalid_raise=False` parameter in the call to `np.genfromtxt`:

```
oompa = np.genfromtxt('C_20k_73_2.tsv',delimiter='\t',
            usecols=(0,1,2),unpack=True,skip_header=13,
            dtype=str, invalid_raise=False)
```

That will skip lines that are inconsistent with the number of columns `np.genfromtxt` expects to parse.

---

If the file is not too long, an easy way to look at the last few lines of the file is

```
print(open(filename, 'rb').read().splitlines()[:-3])
```

Since this prints a list, you get the `repr` of the items in the list without having to call `repr` directly. The `repr` makes it easy to see where the tabs and end-of-line characters are.

By examining the `repr` of the last lines successfully parsed by `np.genfromtxt` compared to the first lines skipped, you should be able to spot the break in pattern which is causing the problem.

---

If the file is very long, you can print the last few lines using

```
import collections
lines = collections.deque(maxlen=2)
with open('data', 'rb') as f:
    lines.extend(f)
print(list(lines))
```

The problem with `open(filename, 'rb').read().splitlines()` is that it reads the entire file into memory and then splits the huge string into a huge list. This can cause a MemoryError when the file is too large. The `deque` has a maximum number of elements, thus preventing the problem so long as the lines themselves are not too long.